# mysql_insert_id doesn't return anything

Tags: php

```
$sql="INSERT INTO wp_comments (comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date, comment_content, user_id) 
                VALUES
              ('$qID', '$author', '$dro', '$content', '$_SESSION[user_id]')";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            die(last_insert_id());
```

When I run this code I see white screen only, so last_insert_id() doesn't seem to return any value... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use mysql_error to see the errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id()` may be the function you are looking for to retrieve the id of the last inserted row.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual on exit (die is an alias of exit):

> If status is a string, this function
>   prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer , that value
>   will be used as the exit status and
>   not printed. Exit statuses should be
>   in the range 0 to 254, the exit status
>   255 is reserved by PHP and shall not
>   be used. The status 0 is used to
>   terminate the program successfully.

If last_insert_id() returns an integer, it won't be printed.

By the way, last_insert_id is not a built-in PHP function. You should also make sure you are using the correct function.

Try this instead (supposing the last_insert_id function is defined):

```
print last_insert_id();
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned, check `mysql_error()` or `mysql_errno()` first. A good way to catch them would be:

```
if (mysql_errno()==0) {
    // all was good
    $last_insert_id = mysql_insert_id();
}
else {
    // error occurred
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/get_last_id_after_insert/) not `last_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `last_insert_id` as a regular MYSQL query inside PHP. Something like this:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM wp_comments");
```